# border color change is working only for first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, game-development

I am trying to make a javascript based small game.

Here is the [Fiddle for the GAME](http://jsfiddle.net/fsMku/3/)

It is almost working except a few issues:-

> 1. On click of any `TD`, if the image is in that `TD`, cell border color should be green otherwise
>      if you have clicked on wrong `TD`, border color turns to red.
>      This functionality is working only first time you start the game. from next time it is always
>      showing red border color.
> 2. Till level 8, the changing of border color is visible, but as you increase the level, user
>      cannot experience whether he has hit the correct cell or not. I want something like as soon as you have hit the correct cell, the color change should be visible and stable until image appears into another cell.

Any improvement in code and suggestion are appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

When you start the game for the second time, you call `startGame()`.

In `startGame()` you have a  `$('td').click()`, that will fire for the second time, so on each click, it will actual click twice (one catch, one miss).

Answer (score 1):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fsMku/4/)

This will do the trick

unbind the click event in the starting

```
$('td').unbind('click');
```

bind the click event on the `startGame()` function

```
$('td').bind('click');
```

unbind the click event on the `stopGame()` function

```
$('td').unbind('click');
```

Problem with your code :-

you are calling click event in the `startGame()` function so for the first time you have one `$('td').click()` function

for the second time you call `startGame()` function there two `$('td').click()` function and so one which creates the mess

**Suggestion for second point**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fsMku/6/)

In function `callStart()` you have placed the below on the top instead place the below code at the end of the this function.

```
$('td').removeClass("insetBorderMiss");
$('td').removeClass("insetBorderCatch");
```

Comment: @Pranav i have updated the answer with the suggestion and demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fsMku/6/

Comment: Ok..thanks ..but this is not making any difference when you play the game at Level 9 .. what i want that as soon as you click on image, the effect should be stable for a while and then go off. one more thing, at level 9, sometimes catch count is also showing wrong..i guess that this is because events are not properly synchronized.

Comment: @Pranav you can remove this `$('td').removeClass("insetBorderMiss");` from `callStart()` so that correct selected remain highlighted

Comment: demo 1-->http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fsMku/10/ demo2-->http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fsMku/7/